# Objective-C method parameter with ^ symbol

Tags: objective-c, function-parameter

One of the method signature in objective-c code

```
-(void)funcName: (const NSString *)name parameter: (void(^)(ClassName *input)) obj
```

The class definition header file is

```
@interface ClassName : NSObject
@property NSObject *data;
@end
```

Now how to prepare and pass the second paramater?

Comment: http://fuckingblocksyntax.com should be helpful

Comment: [developer.apple.com: Working with blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)

Comment: that called a _block_, and you will love them, I guarantee. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass a *block* as a parameter for instance like:

## option 1.

```
[... funcName:@"" parameter:^(ClassName * input) {
    NSLog(@"I'm inside the block!");
}];
```

## option 2.

```
void(^myBlock)(ClassName *) = ^(ClassName * input) {
    NSLog(@"I'm inside the block!");
};

[... funcName:@"" parameter:myBlock];
```

both options can work, you can use whichever makes more sense to you.

Comment: OK, I did not know about block in Objective-C, now I know

Answer (score 0):

When writing your own methods in Objective-C parameters must be explicitly type casted to the data type that you would like to pass through. The ^ symbol signifys that you are passing in a block. If you would like to pass another parameter after the block - you would simply add the next part of the method name followed by the data type, and then your choice of the variable name. You would do so like this:

```
-(void)funcName: (const NSString *)name parameter: (void(^)(ClassName *input)) obj withOtherParameter:(NSString *) param {

// Use it here and do what you will
NSLog(@"Param = %@", param);

}
```

This assumes you are passing in an NSString to be called "param". If you would like to pass in any other data type, just replace the `(NSString *)` with `(NSNumber *)` or `(NSInteger)` before the "param" in the code and then the param variable will be cast as whatever data type you would like.

Comment: __1.)__ I am not sure that was asked, __2.)__ your _suggestion_ is a very bad practice because the blocks should be the last parameters conventionally.

Comment: **1.)** The asker of the question used the words, "Now how to prepare and pass the second parameter?". **2.)** He refers to the other parameter as the **second** multiple times. Second infers it would go after the first, therefore, I wrote the code as such.

Comment: You have given the answer **The ^ symbol signifys that you are passing in a block.** but the code is not I wanted, thanks anyway

Comment: I understand Dickens I apologize I must have misunderstood your question. Glad you understand blocks and passing parameters now!

Comment: the second parameter is about the _block_ which the OP referred to, and the OP has never asked about anything of any third parameter. syntactically your code may be correct but conventionally is wrong, and not a response to the original question. that is all I said. now, you can feel free to correct or remove your answer.